# Christoffel symbols of Riemannian metric with asymptotic decay

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Say we are given an oriented and complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ such that for a compact set $K \subset M$ we have that $ M \setminus K $ is diffeomorphic to the complement of the closed ball $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \bar{B}_{1}(0) $ and furthermore, in the standart coordinates $x_1,...,x_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by this diffeomorphism, the metric looks like
$$ g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + a_{ij}, $$
where $a_{ij} = O(1/r)$, $\partial_k a_{ij} = O(1/r^2)$ and $\partial_l\partial_k a_{ij} = O(1/r^3)$ (essentially, we are supposing $(M,g)$ to be asymptotically flat).

Will it then be true that the Christoffel symbols of first and second order satisfy the following equality?
$$ \Gamma_{ij}^k = \Gamma_{kij} + O(1/r) $$

Comment: I guess you want to assume that $M\setminus K$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n\setminus \overline{B}_1(0)$.

Comment: @AndreasCap true thank you, edited

Comment: Couldn’t you answer this by using the formulas for the Christoffel symbols in terms of the metric and its partial derivatives? If you’ve tried this, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @Deane when expressing $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ in terms of $\Gamma_{kij}$ one must multiply by the coefficients of the inverse matrix of $g_{ij}$. It is here where I get stuck. I might be missing something, but it is not clear to me how the asymptotic behaviour of the metric influences the inverse $(g^{ij})$.

Comment: You need to estimate the matrix $(I +A)^{-1}$ when $A$ is a small matrix. I suggest doing this first when the dimension is $1$, i.e., for scalars. For example, what happens if $A \rightarrow 0$?